# Querying / seting up PostGIS (raster) table to efficiently get all bands at once?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, band, raster2pgsql

I have created a PostGIS raster table from raster2psql.  I have use cases where I might have bands sizes of 114 to 670 bands inside a raster (The number is consistent across a given dataset.)

My problem is there doesn't seem to be a good way to pull out my data on all bands.  I have created a table with all the band information and ran a cross join to get all the bands out, but it can get very slow when I am pulling out all 670 bands of data.

`SELECT ST_Value(rast, band_id, (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(146.1066, -39.00381), 4326))) AS b1, rid FROM rf_raster cross join rf_bands where rid = 226`

(where rid is my simplification to get the correct tile as I am importing my data tiled.)

This takes almost 10 seconds when I am looking for something that will give me a sub second response.

I have been unable to find any simpler or more efficient way to get all of the data out across all bands for my pixel.

I would like to know if there is a known approach for this, or alternatively an option during load that will allow the data to get stored in one bands as the majority of my use cases will want all of the data.

Comment: What is the size of your tiles?

Comment: I've experimented a little, but 10x10 pixels per tile is what I am currently looking at and what my above findings were done against.

Comment: Is 5x5 faster ?